# Javascript code snippet to defend against Input stealing attack

Tags: javascript, security

I want a JavaScript code to protect web page elements from input stealing attack. I want the keystrokes to be intercepted by the registered event handlers and to be masked from the JavaScript on a web page to prevent from various JavaScript attacks.

Comment: What are you looking to achieve? What kind of JS attacks are you talking about? If you control the page, then how can malicious JS code be added?

Comment: See Javascript functions can listen to keyboard events sent to the password field and record those keys. As a result, a hacker can
obtain the user’s cleartext password.I want to mask the key strokes from any JS code running on phishers page.I hope m clear now. I am trying to develop an extension for a browser which will help preventing from phishing scams.I need above working for that.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Don't modern browsers have anti-phishing code already built in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for a JavaScript code that would intercept keystrokes in such a way that no other JavaScript code could intercept keystrokes, which unfortunately is impossible because your code would have to be privileged over other code and this is not how JavaScript works.

Keyloggers is a serious problem that cannot be solved at the application layer, especially using JavaScript if the attacker that you are trying to protect from already controls the JavaScript in the first place.
Even if you could do it, then you presumably still have to send those keystrokes somewhere and other malicious JavaScript code can intercept it in the transit. 
There is no easy way to protect against keyloggers. Read the [Anti-Keylogger Myths](http://www.trusteer.com/list-context/publications/anti-keyloggers-myths) paper by Trusteer for a good start.

You have to make sure that no malicious JavaScript code can ever be executed without knowledge and against the will of your users (because your users will always be able to execute arbitrary code in the context of your page, using bookmarklets if nothing else, and you just have to deal with it). If you are including ads or some third party widgets in your pages then use technologies like [Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) or [ADsafe](http://www.adsafe.org/).

**Update:** I've just read the comment that you've just posted explaining what are you trying to achieve. If you want to write a browser plugin that would stop evil code from getting keystrokes while only allowing good code to get the keystrokes, then you have a more serious problem: how do you tell the good code from the evil code? Everything is just functions, it's not like they have some *good* property set to true or false. The most you could do is entirely block the keydown and keypress events for password fields but besides breaking a lot of code telling users about the strength of their passwords and things like that, you would really gain nothing because the attacker can easily read the password value at some time intervals not even relying on the keyboard events. If you block the ability to read the password value then you'll break code that verifies if two versions of the password match and things like that, and still you wouldn't achieve anything, because the attacker could just read it when the form is submitted, or the AJAX request is posted, et cetera, et cetera, ad nauseam...

Comment: Oh I see. Cant i give my JS code some preference over others?? What if the JS code i want to run is on an extension of the browser?? Thata what i actually want to do!

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't.

Any keylogger worth its dinner will sit between the keyboard driver and the application. By the time the keystroke gets to the browser window and your script — which is *right* at the end of the pipeline — the logging will likely already have occurred.

Instead, persuade your users to look after their computers better and to run virus scans. You could recommend [Rapport](http://www.trusteer.com/product/trusteer-rapport), which UK banks are promoting at present.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want this, do you mean something like this?

```
onkeydown="function(){return false;}"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No Mr David.This is not what i am looking for.

Comment: Can you explain it to me again? What kind of attack do you want to prevent?

Comment: See Javascript functions can listen to keyboard events sent to the password field and record those keys. As a result, a hacker can
obtain the user’s cleartext password.I want to mask the key strokes from any JS code running on phishers page.I hope m clear now. I am trying to develop an extension for a browser which will help preventing from phishing scams.I need above working for that.

Comment: @Divya: Re: *I want to mask the key strokes from any JS code running on phishers page.* - If you know that the user is accessing phishers page then why won't your plugin block the entire page? Remember that it could have no JavaScript at all and use just plain old static HTML forms.

Comment: Ok thats what is the speciality i want with my extension. There are ppl who still ignore the warning given by browsers and continue surfing. So i want the working of my extension go beyond just blocking the page for them. I want it to work even when they continue surfing and are supplying thr credentials. The extension would submit some bogus credentials along and a long process...

Answer (score 0):

Generally the inputs can be intercepted from the following DOM events

```js
    window.onkeydown
    window.onkeypress
    window.onkeyup
    document.onkeydown
    document.onkeypress
    document.onkeyup
```

What you can do it to make it undefined using a script like this [JavaScript Keylogger & Anti-Keylogger](https://cscodez.blogspot.com/2014/05/javascript-keylogger-anti-keylogger.html) this will ensure that there are not actions assigned to these events.

it will be something like this

```js
    // this will attach a listener to the onkeypress() event
    document.onkeypress = function(e){ 
    window.keyp = "";
        window.keyp += e.key;  //we store the key into a window variable to create the complete word
        if(e.code === "Space") // we check for when space is pressed to print the word out in console
        { 
            console.log(window.keyp); //print
            window.keyp = ""; // we made the window variable null again
        } 
    };
```

To overcome this we can have someting as AntiKeylogger and call it when the page is loaded

```js
   //disables the keystroke logging 
    function AntiKeylogger(){
        window.onkeydown = undefined;
        window.onkeypress = undefined;
        window.onkeyup = undefined;
        document.onkeydown = undefined;
        document.onkeypress = undefined;
        document.onkeyup = undefined;
    }();
```

But the result differs & depends on when you execute it if the malicious script executes after a delay or one an event this won't help. Masking involves capturing the event ahead of everyone which seems to be not possible as of now.